# Android Switch, validating before toggling switch

Tags: android, switchcompat

I have a Switch, or a SwitchCompat rather on my app.

When the user clicks or slides the switch I would like to run some code to determine if they should be allowed to.

I have tried the

setOnCheckedChangeListener and setOnClickListener methods but both allow the graphic of the slider to toggle before running the validation code.

How can I run my own code before anything else when the switch is pressed?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `asyncTask`? it will be called on `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Answer (score 0):

you should write your validation code first. if validation is false they not allowed to press switch using setEnabled(false) the else user is allowed to press switch

Answer (score 0):

We have three options

1. One you have tried by `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`
2. Other is to disable the view entirely by using `setEnabled()`
3. You may try using `setOnTouchListener` and write your validation code there, and if the user is not allowed to do the functionality just `return true` else `return false`

Returning true would make the Switch believe the touch was handled and it won't do any actions for the same